# Can't iterate a list using for loop for my values

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook, physics, differential-equations

So this is the function I have for like a standing wave solution to generate the current u:

```
def standing_wave_solution(t,nx,mx,my,x,y):  
    
    dx = (1/nx-1)

    w = math.pi*(math.sqrt((mx**2)+(my**2))) 
    un = math.sin(mx*math.pi*x)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y)*math.cos(w*t)
    ui1 = math.sin(mx*math.pi*x-1)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y)*math.cos(w*t)
    ui2 = math.sin(mx*math.pi*x+1)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y)*math.cos(w*t)
    uj1 = math.sin(mx*math.pi*x)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y-1)*math.cos(w*t)
    uj2 = math.sin(mx*math.pi*x)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y+1)*math.cos(w*t)
    uprev = un-((-4*un)+(ui1)+(uj1)+(ui2)+((uj2)/(dx**2)))
    return uprev,un
```

And then I try applying that function to compute one timestep of the wave which is given by the pseudocode:

[image: Pseudocode for equation]

So my solution for implementing this using the previous function standing_wave_solution is this:

```
def one_time_step(t,mx,my,nx,ny,alpha):
    
    x=np.linspace(0,1,nx)
    y=np.linspace(0,1,ny)
    unext = np.zeros([nx,ny])
    l = np.zeros([nx,ny])
    dx = (1/nx-1)
    dy = (1/ny-1)
    dt = (alpha*dx)/(math.sqrt(2))
    
    
    for i in range(nx-1):
        for j in range(ny-1):
            uprev,ucur = standing_wave_solution(t,nx,mx,my,x[i],y[j])
            if (i==0 or i == nx-1 or j==0 or j == ny-1):
                unext[i][j]=0
            else:
                l = (-4*ucur[i][j])+(ucur[i-1][j])+(ucur[i][j-1])+(ucur[i+1][j])+((ucur[i][j+1])/(dx**2))
                unext[i][j] = (-1*uprev[i][j])+(2*ucur[i][j])+((dt**2)*(l))
    return next


one_time_step(4,4,4,4,4,1)
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-8ddbe6456bbd> in <module>
     21 
     22 
---> 23 one_time_step(4,4,4,4,4,1)

<ipython-input-152-8ddbe6456bbd> in one_time_step(t, mx, my, nx, ny, alpha)
     16                 unext[i][j]=0
     17             else:
---> 18                 l = (-4*ucur[i][j])+(ucur[i-1][j])+(ucur[i][j-1])+(ucur[i+1][j])+((ucur[i][j+1])/(dx**2))
     19                 unext[i][j] = (-1*uprev[i][j])+(2*ucur[i][j])+((dt**2)*(l))
     20     return unext

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Basically all I am trying to do is use my nested for loop that goes till nx and ny to set the. values of uprev and ucur at that specific 'i' and 'j' index so that I can generate a bunch of unexts and store them in a matrix.

Comment: ucur is a number and you're saying ucur[i][j]

Comment: Agree with @bilke your ucur variable appears to be a float. Have you tried printing it?

Comment: Specifically `ucur` comes from `math.sin(mx*math.pi*x)*math.sin(my*math.pi*y)*math.cos(w*t)` which is indeed just a number.

Comment: From memory, I think if you used numpy for this, the above expression for `ucur` would also return an array if `t` or `y` or `x` is also a numpy array. Perhaps that would be more useful to you.